# How do I convert an Excel calculation into a spilled dynamic array

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm not even sure how to ask what I'm looking for, without describing the full question.

if I have this table (CSV form at the bottom if anyone wants it):

[image]
F2: `=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(C:C,ISNUMBER(C:C))))`

G2: `=LET(x,F2#,SUMIFS(B:B,C:C,x,D:D,1))`

I2: `=LET(x,F2#,SUMIFS(B:B,C:C,x,D:D,2))`

One complete pay period is 4hr; there can be up to two pay periods in a day.  But, if there are only a handful of hours used, they can be incrementally combined into another arbitrary day, and get paid-out when a pay period aggregates to 4hr.

I can get H2 to work as:

`=IF(--G2=0,"",LET(x,FILTER(E:E,(C:C=F2)*(D:D=1)),IF(AND(EXACT(x,@x)),@x,"inconsistent")))`

Essentially it ensures that everything in a given pay date/pay period is funded from the same pool, either the base pay pool or the retirement pool.

I can copy/paste that just fine.   But, is there a way H2 can be re-formulated to yield a dynamic spilled range the same length as F2# and G2#?

(In case anyone is curious, this is how US Military Reserve pay works, this is a tracker I'm using to make sure I'm being honest in what I'm claiming.)

CSV form of the above table:

```
Date Performed,Hours,Pay Date,Pay Period,Pay Type,Verification,Period 1,Pay Type,Period 2,Pay Type
1-Oct-21,1.5,24-Sep-22,1,base pay,1-May-22,4,inconsistent,4,base pay
29-Oct-21,1.5,24-Sep-22,1,retirement,2-May-22,2,base pay,,
29-Nov-21,1.5,24-Sep-22,2,retirement,19-May-22,4,base pay,4,base pay
23-Dec-21,1,24-Sep-22,1,retirement,22-Sep-22,,,2.5,retirement
23-Dec-21,2,24-Sep-22,2,retirement,23-Sep-22,4,retirement,2,retirement
27-Jan-22,0.5,24-Sep-22,2,retirement,24-Sep-22,4,inconsistent,4,retirement
2-Feb-22,0.5,23-Sep-22,2,retirement,25-Sep-22,,,3.5,retirement
22-Feb-22,2,23-Sep-22,,retirement,,,,,
27-Feb-22,2.5,23-Sep-22,1,retirement,,,,,
28-Feb-22,0.5,23-Sep-22,2,retirement,,,,,
2-Mar-22,0.5,23-Sep-22,1,retirement,,,,,
3-Mar-22,1,23-Sep-22,1,retirement,,,,,
4-Mar-22,0.5,,2,retirement,,,,,
6-Mar-22,1,23-Sep-22,2,retirement,,,,,
6-Mar-22,2,1-May-22,1,,,,,,
7-Mar-22,2,1-May-22,1,base pay,,,,,
8-Mar-22,,2-May-22,1,base pay,,,,,
8-Mar-22,1.5,25-Sep-22,2,retirement,,,,,
9-Mar-22,1,22-Sep-22,2,retirement,,,,,
10-Mar-22,1,1-May-22,2,base pay,,,,,
13-Mar-22,1.5,1-May-22,2,base pay,,,,,
14-Mar-22,1.5,1-May-22,2,base pay,,,,,
15-Mar-22,1,2-May-22,1,base pay,,,,,
17-Mar-22,1,2-May-22,1,base pay,,,,,
17-Mar-22,2,25-Sep-22,2,retirement,,,,,
18-Mar-22,1,22-Sep-22,2,retirement,,,,,
24-May-22,0.5,22-Sep-22,2,retirement,,,,,
19-May-22,4,19-May-22,1,base pay,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
19-May-22,4,19-May-22,2,base pay,,,,,
```

Edit: originally created with a manual inline table at the top; once I had enough reputation, I replaced with a screenshot.  This was later updated to include blank lines, as suggested by @Jos Woolley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a far easier way to approach this, that demonstrates my initial approach was overly complicated and also incorporates @JosWolley's recommendation to minimize evaluating millions of rows each recalculation.

for the answer, that works for pay period 1:

```
=LET(table,FILTER(B:E,(B:B>0)*(C:C>0)*(D:D=1)),BYROW(F2#,LAMBDA(row,LET(payTypes,INDEX(FILTER(table,(INDEX(table,,2)=row)),,4),consistency,AND(EXACT(payTypes,INDEX(payTypes,1))),IF(ISERR(consistency),"",IF(consistency,INDEX(payTypes,1),"inconsistent"))))))
```

Pay period two simply needs to update `(D:D=1)` to `(D:D=2)` and is otherwise the same.

Here it is, reproduced structurally:

```
=LET(table,FILTER(B:E,(B:B>0)*(C:C>0)*(D:D=1)),
    BYROW(F2#,LAMBDA(row,
        LET(payTypes,INDEX(FILTER(table,(INDEX(table,,2)=row)),,4),
            consistency,AND(EXACT(payTypes,INDEX(payTypes,1))),
                IF(ISERR(consistency),
                    "",
                    IF(consistency,
                        INDEX(payTypes,1),
                        "inconsistent"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ))
)
```

And, reproduced graphically:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why there are still so many who continue to misunderstand which functions can be passed arbitrarily sized ranges (entire columns, for example) with no detriment to calculation performance. Just one instance of a construction such as

`FILTER(E:E,(C:C=F2)*(D:D=1))`

for example, is being forced to iterate over **more than two million cells**, since no implicit detection of the last-used cells within those ranges is employed by that function.

Try this set-up for Period 1:

`=LET(ζ,MMULT(GESTEP(COUNTIFS(C2:C30,F2#,D2:D30,1,E2:E30,TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(E2:E30))),1),SEQUENCE(2,,,0)),IF(ζ=0,"",IF(ζ=1,INDEX(E2:E30,MATCH(F2#&"|1",C2:C30&"|"&D2:D30,0)),"Inconsistent")))`

keeping the ranges passed to a sensible length.

The part

`"|1"`

can be replaced with

`"|2"`

for the equivalent Period 2 set-up, adding an error clause to the above formula if desired (for May 2nd, for example, there is no Pay Period 2 entry).

Comment: a ZETA!  nice, aside from Reimann I can't remember the last time I saw one of those.  Anyway, it needs to be maintainable without modifying the function, and without using an Excel Table. This is an extract to highlight the question, the in-use worksheet has a few hundred entries from the past 6 months, and includes blanks rows in the middle that need to be skipped-over.  Is there a way to reflect "all non-blank rows in column C" without evaluating all of column C, and without special knowledge of the max size of Column C?  I could do C1:C1000 but I'm trying generally to avoid that.

Comment: Sounds like it would be a good idea for you to update your CSV extract with a more realistic dataset, i.e. one including blanks in whichever columns they may appear, together with an updated set of expected results, if applicable.

Answer (score 1):

If using functions is not a requirement for you, you can also use a pivot table.

Go to insert - pivot table - make sure "add to data model" is checked and click ok.

in Power Pivot tab - measures - insert measure and create one with this formula:
`=if (DISTINCTCOUNT([Pay Type])=1,DISTINCT(Table1[Pay Type]),"inconsistent")`

[image]

Comment: I'm not specifically opposed to pivot tables, as long as I can keep it within the sheet.  I can move helper columns to the WAY right so that it's no visible in a normal use of the worksheet.  I have zero experience with Pivot Tables, I hear some people talk about them but the examples I've seen to-date could be accomplished with either formulas or sorting or something like that.  Notably though, I don't have ability to do add-ins, is there a way to do that without Power Pivot?

Comment: Since Excel 2016, Power Pivot is part of excel installation.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out.

If you just want the final answer, here it is:

```
=IF(G2#=0,"",LET(payPeriod,1,payTypes,TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(E:E,(E:E>0)*(E:E<>E1)))),occurencesPerDate,COUNTIFS(C:C,F2#,D:D,payPeriod),resultIfConsistent,INDEX(E:E,MATCH(F2#,(C:C)*(D:D=payPeriod),0)),LET(payMatrix,COUNTIFS(C:C,F2#,D:D,payPeriod,E:E,payTypes),LET(matrixRowCount,MMULT(payMatrix,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(payTypes),1,1,0)),nonBlanksPerMatrixRow,MMULT(--(payMatrix<>0),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(payTypes),1,1,0)),LET(isConsistent,(nonBlanksPerMatrixRow=1)*(occurencesPerDate=matrixRowCount),IF(isConsistent,resultIfConsistent,"inconsistent"))))))
```

First, I think @MátéJuhász is spot-on that using a PivotTable is probably the most straight-forward approach for this.  I had to do some research since I've struggled on this before, but from what I can tell I think a PivotTable only works when all columns and rows of the source dataset have some data. I need to support rows that are fully blank (which I didn't mention before he suggested this), otherwise I would probably dump what I'm doing and try to figure out PivotTables.

Second, for a pure formulaic solution, @JosWoolley got real close, it didn't quite match all the edge cases that I had accounted for, but he pointed out I didn't specify the edge cases originally.

I've updated the question to (hopefully) show these.  I took great inspiration from @JosWoolley and used some of the tricks, especially the `MMULT()` thing to make this work and the `LET()` thing to make it both faster and more readable.

The full equation is complicated, but it breaks down into a number of manageable chunks.  The `LET()` function greatly aids in making the sections readable (er, "approachable" anyway).

First, need need to ensure we're only using results where there's results to have.  For column H, that's pay period 1 (column J changes G2# to I2#, and payPeriod to 2, otherwise everything after is identical between pay period evaluations)

```
=IF(G2#=0,"",LET(payPeriod,1
```

Then we need to calculate pay types used on the worksheet.  Later uses all need this in a horizontal row, and the next calculation step uses it as column headers during R&D:

```
,payTypes,TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(E:E,(E:E>0)*(E:E<>E1))))
```

[image]

We then calculate the number of times each pay date occurs:

```
,occurencesPerDate,COUNTIFS(C:C,F2#,D:D,payPeriod)
```

[image]

And then we calculate what the pay type would be, assuming everything is fully consistent.  Note that errors and inaccurate results are ok here in principle, the portions we actually use should be correct.

```
,resultIfConsistent,INDEX(E:E,MATCH(F2#,(C:C)*(D:D=payPeriod),0))
```

[image]

We next generate a matrix counting the number of times each pay type was used for a given pay date.  For R&D purposes, it's useful to put this part of the calculation diretly below payTypes; it will spill horizontally as far as needed and will align visually to use payTypes essentially as column headers.

```
,LET(payMatrix,COUNTIFS(C:C,F2#,D:D,payPeriod,E:E,payTypes)
```

[image]

The next step is interesting.  We collapse payMatrix into a single-column array where each row is the sum of all entries per-row in payMatrix.  this is accomplished by matrix-multiplying payMatrix array by another array of all 1's that is 1-column wide and the same number of rows as there are columns in PayTypes.

```
,LET(matrixRowCount,MMULT(payMatrix,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(payTypes),1,1,0))
```

[image]

And then, count the number of non-blank cells per row (later we'll test to ensure there's exactly a single non-blank cell per row):

```
,nonBlanksPerMatrixRow,MMULT(--(payMatrix<>0),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(payTypes),1,1,0))
```

[image]

And for the final calculation, we generate a table of 1's and 0's that are the consistency test:

```
,LET(isConsistent,(nonBlanksPerMatrixRow=1)*(occurencesPerDate=matrixRowCount)
```

[image]

The last step altogether is fairly straightforward.
If there's no payDate+payPeriod, return "" (note, this test was performed at the very beginning)
If payDate+payPeriod don't have all the same payTypes, return "inconsistent"
If both tests pass through, return the actual payType used for payDate+payPeriod

```
,IF(isConsistent,resultIfConsistent,"inconsistent"))))))
```

@JosWoolley pointed out that this is highly inefficient in that I'm testing entire million-row columns (C:C, etc) rather than just the portions I need to evaluate.  Performance profiling on my machine showed it worked fast enough on a few hundred rows.  I suspect a number of the columns could be row-limited in a number of situations by only doing it once, probably as a first step, `FILTER(C:E,(C:C<>"")*(C:C<>C1)*((D:D=1)+D:D=2)))`.  If I ever find I need to optimize this further, that will likely be my first step, but for now the formula is over-complicated enough as it is.

Also, I'm very confident the formula's architecture as a whole is overly complicated.  It would benefit from being stripped-down of the parts that aren't necessary, and possibly even taking a whole different approach altogether.